# How to convert 16 bit Gray Scale image to RGB image in java?

Tags: java, image, swing, jai

I'm making a desktop app in Java Swing using the Netbeans platform. I want to convert a 16 bit gray scale image to an RGB image. How can I do that?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Use [`ImageJ`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/).

Comment: Can I use LookUp Table for convert 16 bit Gray_Scale to RGB? if Yes , than how to use LookUp table for conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Grayscale is held in a single value, black, whereas RBG is held in three, red, blue, and green.  The best you can do with this is a monochromatic image, which you can do with the `getRGB(x, y)` method in the `BufferedImage` class.  Since your input image is in grayscale, you can take any of the three color values from that because they should be the same.  Then use that value for whatever color you choose to be the basis of the monochrome.

Here's an example with red:

```
public BufferedImage changeToRedMonochrome(BufferedImage grayImage)
{
    int width = grayImage.getWidth();
    int height = grayImage.getHeight()

    BufferedImage redImage = new BufferedImage(
        width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    for (int y=0; y<height; y++)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<width; x++)
        {
            Color grayColor = new Color(grayImage.getRGB);
            int gray = grayColor.getRed();

            int red = (gray > 127) ? 255 : gray/2;
            int blue = (gray > 127 ? gray/2 : 0;
            int green = (gray > 127 ? gray/2 : 0;

            Color redColor = new Color(red, blue, green);
            redImage.setRGB(x, y, redColor);
        }
    }
}
```

It's not perfect code, and of course you would need to adjust it to fit your specific needs, but this is one way you could make a monochromatic image.

Comment: The redColor variable is ignored in your example... Of course the red, green, blue components have to be set to the same value, and hopefully exactly this is happening after grayImage.getRGB(x, y) (I didn't check, but looks promising)

Comment: Good point, I apologize for missing that.  I've fixed it.  If you used a BufferedImage with the type TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, then it should by default have equal color values.

Comment: If only the red color is set, then the resulting image will be black-and-red instead of black-and-white... I would only use grayColor in order to have a resulting image that looks similar to the input image.

Comment: Ah, well if you want the full monochromatic spectrum, then you have to account for the white half, too.  I've modified the code again to account for the grayscale value below and above 50%.

Comment: I don't fully understand your intention, but I am sure that if you want to have a shade of gray at the end, then the red, green and blue components should always have exactly the same value... What I meant is that the grayColor variable already contains the correct value (because getRGB handles the color space conversion, see the Javadoc for getRGB, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29), you can use that in setRGB without any change. Also see my other answer to the original question.

Comment: Half of the spectrum is additive while the other is subtractive.  That might not sound like it makes sense.  In grayscale, absolute gray (r127-b127-g127), is the center of the spectrum.  For red monochrome, however, absolute red (r255-b0-g0) is the center.  So, for the first half of the red monochromatic spectrum as we go toward the center, we're adding red to black (r0-b0-g0 to r255-b0-g0).  In the second half as we go toward the center, we're subtracting everything that's not red from white (r255-b255-g255 to r255-b0-g0).  Put the two halves together, and you have the full spectrum.

Comment: This is interesting, but does not change the fact, that getRGB does not deliver the raw data, but does all the necessary color space conversion :) See the JavaDoc.

Comment: Oh well, I tried :)  Besides, going back to the question, not much was actually specified as to whether they wanted the image in color or simply in RGB format.

Comment: thanks for your replay. Can I use LookUp Table for convert 16 bit Gray_Scale to RGB? if Yes , than how to use LookUp table for conversion?

Answer (score 1):

The getRGB/setRGB method described by Incompl should work. But, its performance is rather poor, if I remember correctly (these methods do a lot of work that is unnecessary in this case). I think it would be much faster to draw on the new image and let Java to optimize the conversion from `BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY` to `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB`:

```
int width = grayImage.getWidth();
int height = grayImage.getHeight()

BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(
    width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();  
g.drawImage(grayImage, 0, 0, null);  
g.dispose();
```

Comment: Can I use LookUp Table for convert 16 bit Gray_Scale to RGB? if Yes , than how to use LookUp table for conversion?