# BufferedImage - getting the value of a pixel in grayscale color model picture

Tags: java, pixel, grayscale

I have an `BufferedImage` transformed to grayscale using this code. I usually got the pixel values by `BufferedImage.getRGB(i,j)` and the gor each value for R, G, and B. But how do I get the value of a pixel in a grayscale image?

EDIT: sorry, forgot abou the conversion.

```
static BufferedImage toGray(BufferedImage origPic) {
    BufferedImage pic = new BufferedImage(origPic.getWidth(), origPic.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    Graphics g = pic.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(origPic, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    return pic;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you used to convert it?

Comment: "using this code." where is the code?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

if you have RGB image so you can get the (Red , green , blue , Gray) values like that:

```
BufferedImage img;//////read the image
int rgb = img.getRGB(x, y);
int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = (rgb & 0xFF);
```

and the gray is the average for (r , g , b), like this:

```
int gray = (r + g + b) / 3;
```

but if you convert RGB image(24bit) to gray image (8bit) :

```
int gray= img.getRGB(x, y)& 0xFF;/////////will be the gray value
```

Comment: Interested in knowing how to get alpha value of a pixel

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati alpha is (rgb >> 24) & 0xFF

Comment: Hey Alya, now that I have that, how can I create the RGB with a new Gray value?

Comment: it's impoosiple to get RGB from Gray image , because you haven't information to do it , to get gray so you will use the 3 values to get it (R, G , B) after you get the gray , you will lose the values information

Comment: Read this answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226074/how-to-convert-16-bit-gray-scale-image-to-rgb-image-in-java , and search on google to understand why you can't make this conversion , or at least return the colored image as you have

Comment: Is there any other way to set the new value of a pixel in a grayscaled image?

Comment: what do you mean?? you need to return the gray image??!!

Comment: Yes, I needed to return the gray image. To set the new RGB, I just used the same value for the RED, GREEN, and BLUE when creating a new RGB. Worked fine.